# Setting zoom for layer disappearance in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have got 2 working codes, where one is a bit longer and another a bit shorter. Is it some way to bind all these layers as a one group?

The first one is:

```
 map.on('zoomend', function() {
if (map.getZoom() <6){
        map.removeLayer(job);
    }else{
    map.addLayer(job);
    }
    if (map.getZoom() <7){
        map.removeLayer(job2);
    }else{
    map.addLayer(job2);
    }
    if (map.getZoom() <8){
        map.removeLayer(job3);
    }else{
    map.addLayer(job3);
    }
  });
```

and another one

```
   map.on('zoomend', function() {
     if (map.getZoom() <8){
        map.removeLayer(job);
    }
    if (map.getZoom() <8){
        map.removeLayer(job2);
    }
    if (map.getZoom() <8){
        map.removeLayer(job3);
    }
     else {
        map.addLayer(job);
        map.addLayer(job2);
        map.addLayer(job3);
    }
   });
```

I would like to avoid this kind of repeats, as I am going to have multitude of layers in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case a better way is using a predefined mapping (as [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) holding the relations between *zoom* limits and respective *jobs*.
Then, just iterate through the mapping and perform add/remove operation:

```
const zoomJobsMap = new Map([
  [6, job],
  [7, job2],
  [8, job3],
  ...
]);

map.on('zoomend', function() {
    let zoom = map.getZoom();   # get zoom value at once
    for (var [zoomLimit, jobObj] of zoomJobsMap) {
        (zoom < zoomLimit)? map.removeLayer(jobObj) : map.addLayer(jobObj);

    }
}
```